# How do I fix "No Directionality widget found." issue?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to change the background color of the app when the button is pressed. However, When I click it an error pops out.

I tried packing everything in a card, placing in a container, placing in Material App and added a setState method.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(
  myStateFulWidget(

  )
  );
}
class myStateFulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _myStateFulWidgetState createState() => _myStateFulWidgetState();
}

class _myStateFulWidgetState extends State<myStateFulWidget> {
   changeColor(){
    setState(() {
      var colorPart = Colors.red;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Card(
    child:Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Text("Ola",textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
        onPressed: (){
          changeColor();
        },
      ),
    )
  );
  }
}
```

The error that I keep on getting is:

```
 ════════ Exception Caught By widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building InkWell(gestures: [tap], clipped to BoxShape.rectangle, dirty, dependencies: [_FocusMarker], state: _InkResponseState<InkResponse>#6fdbb):
No Directionality widget found.
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting

> `No Directionality widget found` exception

is because there's no parent widget to provide direction information to use with `RaisedButton` textDirection value you provided. This can be solved by providing a `Directionality` widget or another one providing `TextDirection` information from its context like `Scaffold`.

Note that the background color will only be visible in parts not covered by other widgets.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  runApp( MyStatefulWidget());
}


class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {

  var colorPart = Colors.green;

  changeColor(){
    setState(() {
      colorPart = colorPart == Colors.red ? Colors.green : Colors.red ;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: colorPart,
        body: Center(
          child: Card(
              child:Container(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  //color: Colors.black,
                  child: Text("Ola",textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
                  onPressed: (){
                    changeColor();
                  },
                ),
              )
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more about what is happening here : colorPart = colorPart == Colors.red ? Colors.green : Colors.red ;

Comment: It is to set color as red when it's green, and vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using this :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(
      myStateFulWidget(

      )
  );
}
class myStateFulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _myStateFulWidgetState createState() => _myStateFulWidgetState();
}

class _myStateFulWidgetState extends State<myStateFulWidget> {
Color col = Colors.green;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home:new
        Scaffold(
        backgroundColor:col ,
        body:Card(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Ola",textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
            onPressed: (){
              changeColor();
            },
          ),
        )
      )
    );
  }
  changeColor(){
    setState(() {
       col = Colors.red;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `var colorPart = Colors.red` in the state out of setstate